# Angular project does not work with @babylonjs/viewer

Tags: angular, typescript

I installed @Angular/Cli@11.0.0 globally. I created an Angular project using command-line "ng new BabylonTest --routing false --style css --skip-git --skip-tests". CD to the folder 'BabylonTest', I then installed @babylonjs/viewer 4.2.0 by typing 'npm install @babylonjs/viewer --save'. Inside the typescript file 'app.component.ts', I imported @babylonjs/viewer by adding the line 'import * as BabylonViewer from '@babylonjs/viewer'. Inside the template file 'app.component.html', I deleted everything and only added an html element as below ', then when I compiled it by typing 'ng serve', it returned the following error:

Error: src/app/app.component.html:4:1 - error NG8001: 'babylon' is not a known element:

1. If 'babylon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

4

```
src/app/app.component.ts:8:16
  8   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

I am not sure what was wrong with my codes, was I missing something? I was using this link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babylonjs/viewer to get the usage of @babylonjs/viewer.
```

Comment: Sorry that I missed the html element added is: "<babylon id="babylon-viewer" camera.behaviors.auto-rotate="0"></babylon>"

Answer (score 0):

As the babylon viewer project exports a WebComponent not an Angular Component, you need to add the custom elements schema to your `@NgModule` defintition like so:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA], // <= this line
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Also, it seems need to add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to @NgModule Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to help you out.